# understanding cascading and css initial

Tags: html, css

So I have this `html` with `css`

```css
.paragraphs {
  color: orange;
  background-color: gray;
}

p.first {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}

p.second {
  color: initial;
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphs">
  <p class="first">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="second">Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

Both have a `background-color` of `gray` but `p.first` would have a `color` of `orange` and `p.second` would have a `color` of `black`.

Why would `background-color` not go back to it's default state with `background-color: initial;` but `color: initial;` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `initial` of `background-color` on a `p`-tag is `transparent` or `none`.

You can also see the computed style of your second `p` tag when inspecting the elements. There you will see that `background-color` has actually the value `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` which is the same as a transparent black.

There is a good article [on quirksmode.org about inherit, initial and unset values](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html).

Comment: This make sense.  Didn't think about the default being `transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you define to `div.paragraphs` is not inherited by `p.first` and `p.second`. It would if your CSS be like this:

```
p {
  color: orange;
  background-color: gray;
}

p.first {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}

p.second {
  color: initial;
  background-color: initial;
}
```

Now all paragraphs (`<p>` tags) will inherit. Paragraphs with a class `first` and `second` will overwrite these values with the ones given.

Answer (score 0):

If you position your `p` elements outside of the parent, you can easily understand what's going on. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6pyo7s1o/)**

`inherit` means the same as the parent.
`initial` means the default values which for background is transparent and for color is black.